# In yii2, loading a namespace with its full path does not work, but using `use` does

Tags: yii, namespaces

Under yii2

```
new yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException();
```

not work but

```
use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;
new ForbiddenHttpException();
```

works why?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.qualified).

> Names that contain a backslash but do not begin with a backslash like my\name can be resolved in 2 different ways.
>
> If there is an import statement that aliases another name to my, then the import alias is applied to the my in my\name.
>
> Otherwise, the current namespace name is prepended to my\name.

So without importing you need to write it like this:

```
new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException();
```